# How do i remove the box around the logo.png?

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

So i'm kinda new to this whole thing, i have a class in my new school about web design that i started about 1 1/2 week ago.
I've just started doing my page for the class i'm in to learn html, css and javascript which are the mains we are using, so it's not original or fill any kind of function that no other website have, i'll start my personal page when i'm done with this one.

You can see a screenshot of my page at the bottom of the post, there are a lot things that i'll improve later one but the main thing right now are the Instagram and Twitter logos at the top of the page, i've wrote a script so when i click either of those, a confirmation box will pop up so i can either choose to leave the page to goto Liverpool FCs twitter/insta or stay on the page

Now the problem I have is that there are boxes around the logos and i have no idea how to remove them, as the logos are .png, so i'm guessing the boxes are just from the script I wrote, so i'm just wondering if someone with a lot more experience than me(lol)knows how to remove the boxes.

Here is the coding(they are kinda bad structured so sorry for that)(im using brackets)(also new to stackoverflow so im not sure if i posted this correctly)

Website: [image]
  Coding: [image]

Comment: Don't post code in the form of image, you can write it in your question.

Comment: If there's not white background in the images (which is perfectly possible for png files) there's probably some `background-color` set in your css styles for `img`, `button`s or `a`. Side note: it won't work if both javascript functions have the same name and the `<a href>` could be omitted.

Comment: Don't wrap a link in a button. Style the link as a button instead

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. I really appreciate your motivation to get better with asking on SO. In this spirit, you can skip the first paragraph of your question because it's not relevant to the question at all. Also, all the comment above :) Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: @MoshFeu Hi! Im sorry about that, i just dont want people to slander me because they think im not as good at coding as them, ive experienced that, so i wanted to put context behind it so my work and questions would fit how experienced i am, i wont do it again

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing it's because you put the logo inside a button tag. Try adding a class to those buttons, and set the opacity of it to 0.

```
.logoswithbuttons{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you possibly show me how that would look? I'm kinda slow in my thinking

Comment: I did make the buttons non-visible but the problem is that the logo isnt a 'button' now since i separated them

Comment: @Jaame72 you don't need to separate them. Add your image to a button, and set the button's opacity to 0. It will make that box around the image disappear, and myPage() still will be called when you click the image.

Comment: I think i know what you are getting at but it kinda still confuses me, i shouldnt putt the image into a button tag but how would i make that image an actual button then?

Comment: Actually i just fixed it, i just selected button to background: transparent and it disappeared, shouldve thought of that earlier